How to run an Angular website on a Linux-based Azure app service
I'm trying to run the out-of-the box Angular website on a Linux-based Azure app service. Although the base Angular website could be run as a static website, I do not plan for the future, customized site to be static, so an Azure web service seems more appropriate as a proof-of-concept. I can successfully build the solution and upload it to an Azure repo. I can deploy the solution to Azure, but when I try to run it, Azure responds with "404 Not Found." I've set the startup command to
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa or
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/dist --no-daemon

with no luck. I've adjusted the index.html file to be
<base href="/"> or
<base href=".">

Nothing is working. Do you have any suggestions?

Use this  startUp Command
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/dist//browser --no-daemon --spa
